# BackgroudnWorker ProgressChanged InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, invalidoperationexception

When I call to the `ProgressChanged` method I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException` I found out on MSDN that this happens because the `WorkerReportsProgress` is set to `false` but it is set to true in my program.

This is the BW initializations:

```
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

The call to the Progress:

```
   tempNetwork.Nodes.Add(tempNode);
   bw.ReportProgress(1, tempNetwork);
```

`tempNetwork` is local

Comment: More information/code needed to analyze the problem.

Comment: What is `tempNetwork`, what `tempNode`? Are you creating GUI elements in bgw?

Comment: @JeffRSon not binded UI elements, they are model elemnets that i'm adding to the Main UI element (`Network`) on the main thread (in the `progressChanged`)

Comment: GUI elements must not be created in a non-GUI thread. Where you actually add those is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm creating a temp Model element and then passing it to the `progressChanged` to be added to the binded UI element

Comment: InvalidOperationException has more than one cause.  WPF is very picky about where you create objects.  The exception details would show the cause, you should never omit the message and the stack trace from a question.